# Open executable and manage its streams?

Tags: ruby, io, stream, popen3

I'm trying to open a Ruby script that prompts for stuff with `popen3`, for testing purposes.

I need to be able to type into the STDIN of the proccess and inspect the outputs. So far I have this:

```
require 'open3'
def run(executable, opts = {})
  Signal.trap('CLD') do
    puts 'STDIN:', @stdout.readlines
    # @stderr.rewind
    puts 'STDERR:', @stderr.readlines
    # got EOF, trying to rewind gives me 'Errno::ESPIPE: Illegal seek'

    [@stdin, @stdout, @stderr].each &:close
  end

  @stdin, @stdout, @stderr, @thread = Open3.popen3(executable)
  @status = @thread.value
end
```

Have been trying for days, my brain is melting.

Comment: I advise you to do this only as a last effort - if possible, use the same library your software is using instead of lunch the other process and try to deal with it.

Comment: Yeah, it proved to be really hard (and time consuming). However, I'll answer if I can.

Comment: readlines "blocks" until it reads all input, so...probably use something else...

Answer (score 0):

The things you are allowed to do in a signal handler are very limited. For example, [you are not allowed to do I/O in a signal handler](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/SIG30-C.+Call+only+asynchronous-safe+functions+within+signal+handlers). Signal handlers are notoriously easy to do wrong.

What do you think about using `Open3.capture*`? It avoids all blocks/race conditions when reading from stdout and stderr at the same time. Besides, it allows you to pass data for stdin. Use the keyword argument `:stdin_data`!